# Convert a Relative Layout to a Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm developing an Android app, and for the graphic part I'm using the useful editor of Android Studio. This means that I'm moving the objects with the margin commands to make them fit the Google Pixel C screen perfectly. Now I tried the app on the tablet and, of course, it doesn't works. I read that I should be using a Linear Layout, but I think that the code I want to convert doesn't respect its rules, because I've elements on every row and in a different position. How can I represent it with a Linear Layout? This is the code, as you can see it has a specified margin for each element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main"
    android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="1063dp"
        android:layout_height="476dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="275dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kotta_one"
        android:text="Test del pensiero\n      divergente"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="78dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="123dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/invioA"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="680dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/invioB"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kotta_one"
        android:text="Area\nDocenti"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#030000"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Setting margins to position elements would defeat the purpose of layout, you are supposed to tell the rules to layout and layout positions items for you. Margin is supposed to be for extra spacing between views/elements not for positioning. Take a look at following link to learn how to build UI with ConstraintLayout:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: screenshot of the desired Layout will be helpful

Comment: @afhamu I added the screen

Comment: Do you want the app to fit in both the Tablet and Phones?

Comment: @afhamu Only tablets

Comment: will this do?  https://i.imgur.com/jIHP9zp.png

Comment: @afhamu Yes, it's perfect!

Comment: Find the code at my second Answer and try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197473/discussion-between-afhamu-and-fabio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_3"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="Area\nDocenti"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#030000"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kotta_one"
        android:text="Test del pensiero\n      divergente"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Protocollo A"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Protocollo B"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to use `ConstraintLayout`: [read about it here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

but something quick and hacky for LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_margin_start="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kotta_one"
        android:text="Area\nDocenti"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#030000"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_gravity="centre"
     android:gravity="centre">
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kotta_one"
        android:text="Test del pensiero"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kotta_one"
        android:text="divergente"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

                 <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button_1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                   android:text="@string/invioA"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                   android:textSize="18dp"/>

                <Button
                   android:id="@+id/button_2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                   android:text="@string/invioB"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                   android:textSize="18dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

That might not be perfect as I just wrote it free hand, but I think it gives you a good idea of what you can do.